# Turning on a hidden button on a page when an action is performed on another page

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am developing a xamarin forms application and have two pages. Here is a list of
what I have

1. Page1 has a listview and a hidden button
2. When you click on a row on page1 it takes you to page2 where you can edit that row
3. Once you are done editing on Page2 and click on back button, I want the hidden button to be enabled on Page1
4. The hidden button should only be enabled when you make a change in page2

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use MessagingCenter

Comment: How? what is MessagingCenter?

Answer (score 1):

MessagingCenter is part of Xamarin Forms

in Page2, whenever you do an action that should enable the button

```
MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this,"TurnOnButton");
```

in Page1, in your constructor

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this,"TurnOnButton", () => {
  myButton.IsVisible = true;
});
```

Comment: As easy as that? Is there any namespace i need to add or something? I guess I can check that

Comment: Is TurnOnButton the name of my button in xaml?

Comment: no, myButton is your button.  TurnOnButton is the message that you're passing from one page to another.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center